# How to remove the letter "Z" from the end of a dateTime

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove the Z from the end of a dateTime entity. The timezone of the API gets confused from the site I'm pushing the date from. Does anyone know a script that can remove the Z when a user types in a dateTime?

Comment: Sounds like you date is in ISO 8601 format (usually a good thing).  Can't you just parse it?

Comment: ```console.log(new Date().toISOString().replace('T', ' ').split(".")[0])```
Output: ```2021-06-15 13:46:11```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're using UTC Date i'm guessing. You can try to use `.toLocaleString()` on your date time object.

Example

```
var datetime = new Date();
var now = datetime.toLocaleString();
```

This should get you something like this: `6/30/2017, 8:47:15 AM`

Another option if you want to maintain the format and just remove the T and Z characters is to replace the strings. Example:

```
var datetime = new Date();
var now = datetime.toISOString().replace('Z', '').replace('T', '');
```

Comment: var c = str.dateTime(str.length-1,str.length-1)
if(c = ‘Z’)
str = str.dateTime(0,str.length-2)

Comment: Do you think this would do something similar to the Z?